# Как правильно уложить товар в корзину?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет.

Есть функция `addToCart`, которая при нажатии ***В корзину*** собирает данные о состоянии карточки товара `ID - артикул, цвет и кол-во`, которое нужно добавить.
`var = articul, color и quantity` соответственно.

Вопрос: как это всё правильно положить в объект, чтобы потом достать в корзину?

***Должно выглядеть как-то так:***

```
{
3:чёрный - 10,белый - 2;  
7:зелёный - 3,жёлтый-11 
и тд...
}
```

Comment: приведите код Вашей функции addToCart

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vun3jfgy/

Comment: Cart сделать массивом объектов и добавлять туда. Элементом будет объект который хранит артикул, количество и т.д. Удалять аналогично - удалить из массива.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не очень понял, что за корзина. Если у Вас не получается добавить данные из каких-то полей в объект, то сделать можно как-то так, используя ид_продукта к примеру:

```js
var cart = {}

function addToCart() {
  var product_id = $('#product_id').val();
  const currentProduct = 'product' + product_id;
  var articul = 'articul1' + product_id;
  var color = '#0cf';


// добавить данные в объект, ключ - ид продукта
  cart[product_id] = {
    'currentProduct': currentProduct,
    'articul': articul,
    'color': color
  }

  $('#modal-basket').html($('#modal-basket').html() + '<p>Товар' + product_id + '</p>' + getHtml(cart[product_id]));
  console.log(cart);
}

function getHtml(arr) {
  var html = '';
  html += 'Продукт: ' + arr.currentProduct + '<br />';
  html += 'Артикул: ' + arr.articul + '<br />';
  html += 'Цвет: ' + arr.color + '<br />';
  return html;
}
```

```css
div#modal-basket {
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="product_id" value="1" />
<input type="button" id="addToCart" value="addToCart" onclick="addToCart()" />
<div id="modal-basket"></div>
```

UPD. Обновил ответ по Вашему комментарию. В Вашу функцию добавил код добавления товара в объект cart. Надеюсь, правильно понял и нужно это.

```
function addToCart(e) {
  const currentProduct = $(e.currentTarget).closest('.product');
  var articul = $(this).attr('data-art');
  var color = $('.btn-color.active', currentProduct).text().trim();
  var quantity = $('.quantity-input', currentProduct).val();

  /////////
  var product_id = 'a'+articul+'c'+color;
  if (cart[product_id]) {
    // Если товар с выбранным цветом есть в коизине, обновим количество:
    cart[product_id]['quantity'] += quantity;
  } else {
    // Если нет - добавим новый товар в корзину:
    cart[product_id] = {
      'articul' : articul,
      'color' : color,
      'quantity' : quantity
    }
  }
  ////////////

  document.getElementById('modal-basket').innerHTML = Object.values(cart);
  console.log(cart);
  showMiniCart();
}
```

Comment: У меня articul это и есть ид . Нужно чтоб в объекте было это ид товара, потом какой цвет выбран и количество товара этого цвета.Если этот товар с этим цветом уже есть в корзине, то прибавить кол - во  просто

Comment: @МакСкири Обновил ответ.  Я просто в Вашу функцию дописал добавление/обновление объекта, должно работать по идее

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =   
'color' = color;      
'quantity' = quantity;

Comment: @МакСкири да, там долно быть `'color': color, 'quantity': quantity`, конечно же, в спешке пишу ))

Comment: А так работает, но когда выбираешь товар, который уже есть в корзине с другим цветом, оно не добавляет его, а заменяет.

Comment: Насчет `3+6=36` у вас где-то строка, наверное. Используйте не просто переменные, а оберните их в `parseInt(ваша_переменная)`. Например, `parseInt(quantity)`. Насчет замены товара - не понимаю. Наше условие явно говорит, что заменить товар нужно только тогда, когда он есть и его цвет совпадает с выбранным. Должно работать, по идее. Проверил в консоли на простом примере - все ок у меня

Comment: Со строкой решил.А товар заменяется почему - то. Было `2: {color: "Чёрный", quantity: 1}` , выбираю 2 красный и первое заменяется на красный

Comment: @МакСкири а можете обновленную вашу функцию прислать? Или сайт, где Вы это делаете ) Мне тестировать неудобно ) Условие работает правильно...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vun3jfgy/2/    Заменяется только когда ид одинаковые, другие ид нормально добавляются

Comment: @МакСкири да, правда, ид-то у нас одинаковое было... Ответ обновил. В качестве ключа товара должен быть какой-то уникальный идентификатор. В данном случае можно сделать `var product_id = 'a'+articul+'c'+color;`, то есть строка артикул + цвет.

Comment: То, что надо! Большое спасибо!

Comment: @МакСкири не за что, рад что удалось помочь ))